# Best practice to create a new array from another array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Here is my code that works but I'm looking for a solution thats even cleaner. Im trying to avoid having to initalize my array first.

```
users = []
employees_to_import.each do |employee|
  users << User.new(employee.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :email))
end
```

Is there a method in ruby that I can call to do something like this?

```
users = employees_to_import.push_each do |employee|
  User.new(employee.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :email))
end
```

Not sure if a method like this exists, I didn't see anything in the docs but I figured I would ask.

Comment: You could use [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object): `employees_to_import.each_with_object([]) { |employee, users|
  users << User.new(employee.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :email)) }`. Here `map` (as @AmitA has used) is preferable, but `each_with_object` is the method of choice in many other situations. Among other things (pertaining to scope), `each_with_object` avoids the need to first define the object (`users = []`) and then return it after the block (`users`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `map` method:

```
users = employees_to_import.map do |employee|
  User.new(employee.slice(:first_name, :last_name, :email))
end
```

It is also aliased as `collect`.

From the documentation ([here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)):

The `map` and `collect` basically return a new array with the results of running block once for every element:

```
(1..4).map { |i| i*i }      #=> [1, 4, 9, 16]
```